# Manejo de archivos y listas Python

Tags: python

Tengo un archivo txt con paises y habitantes.

```
Argentina, 50538000
Mexico, 25003045
Nicaragua, 10033009
Chile 15473100
España,30500521
Brasil, 40382909
Bolivia, 11384230
Estados Unidos, 35922456
Rusia, 65690234
```

En el cual tengo que ir actualizando la cantidad de habitantes por pais.
Mi codigo es:

```
lista = [] #Lista vacia
eleg_pais=input("Elegir pais que desea actualizar") #Elegir el pais
nuev_hab=int(input("Ingresar la cantidad de nuevos habitantes"))#Cantidad de habitantes
pais=str(pais)
habitantes= int(habitantes)
contenido= str()
archivo= open("registros.txt", "r")
linea= archivo.readlines()
for linea in archivo:
    if pais in linea:
        contenido += pais + "," + habitantes + "\n"
    else:
        contenido += linea

archivo.close()
```

Me sale error porque las variables pais y habitantes no estan definidas, no se como seguirlo, me podrian ayudar?

Comment: En las lineas 4 y 5 `pais=str(pais);, habitantes= int(habitantes)` haces referencia a pais y habitantes sin que estos existan.

Comment: Lo que no entiendo es que hacer para que existan, asi pueda validarlas.

Comment: No quiero sonar rudo, pero debes empezar por aprender los conceptos básicos de programación en Python y cualquier lenguaje (Como la creacion de variables). Por otra parte, este es un tutorial para manejo de archivos en Python: http://diwo.bq.com/python-leer-archivo/. Saludos

Comment: Lei el tutorial muchas gracias. Lo que me suena raro es que no nos enseñaron diccionarios y nos dijeron que esto se hace con listas y archivos. Y no nos mencionaron "replace"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes varios problemas de lógica en tu texto. No necesitas diccionarios en absoluto para hacer esto, solo tienes que entender que no deberías alterar el texto de una lista sino su index.

```
lista = [] # Lista vacía.
eleg_pais = input("Elegir país que desea actualizar: ") # Elegir el país.
nuev_hab = int(input("Ingresar la cantidad de nuevos habitantes: ")) # Cantidad de habitantes.

# Cargamos el archivo en memoria
with open("registros.txt", "r") as archivo: # El "with" cerrará solo el archivo.
    # Reemplazamos los datos que queremos.
    lineas = archivo.readlines()

# Ejecutamos el cambio que queremos hacer
for index, linea in enumerate(lineas): # Enumerate te da un index.
    pais, habitantes = linea.split(",") # Dividimos cada linea en variables.
    if pais == eleg_pais:
        lineas[index] = "{0}, {1}".format(pais, int(habitantes) + nuev_hab)

# Guardamos el archivo con los datos reemplazados
with open("registros.txt", "w") as guardando:
    guardando.write("".join(lineas))
```

**Nota:** Ten cuidado que en Chile falta la coma, en tu archivo de texto.
**Nota 2:** El código asume que el formato de tu archivo de registro es "Pais, Habitantes", si alguna linea no usa ese formato y pones cosas como "Pais: Habitantes" tendrás errores a menos que cambies el carácter en el `split`.

**Actualización:**
En caso de querer añadir otro valor, como por ejemplo nacimientos, tendrías que editar estas dos lineas:

```
    # Dividimos cada linea en variables, usando la coma para dividir datos.
    pais, habitantes, nacimientos = linea.split(",") 
    # Los simbolos {} sirven para asignar variables con un formato especifico.
    lineas[index] = "{0}, {1}, {2}".format(pais, int(habitantes) + nuev_hab, nacimientos)
```

Creo que tienes dudas sobre como funciona `format` así que deberías buscarlo. Pero en resumidas cuentas lo que hace es esto:

```
"tengo {0} años y quiero {1} millones de {2}".format("29", "mil", "dolares")  
# tengo 29 años y quiero mil millones de dolares
```

Comment: Nota: readlines no es eficiente, readlines siempre será una muy mala idea.

Comment: No existen más de 300 países en el mundo (desconozco el numero total) por lo que el archivo nunca será lo suficiente grande para que sea un problema.

Comment: Eso es verdad. Sin embargo, sobre todo para los que están aprendiendo, es sensato recomendarles usar cosas buenas siempre :)

Comment: Entonces dejemosle como deberes que aprenda a usar `archivo.read()` y que parsee la información por su cuenta :P

Comment: @Saelyth `archivo.read()` es igual de ineficiente, por cargar en memoria el archivo completo :-) Supongo que te referías a `archivo.readline()`. En cualquier caso, en mi opinión, el patrón que deberíamos enseñar para leer un archivo por líneas es `for linea in archivo:`

Comment: El profesor nos recomendo readlines. Por eso en mi anterior codigo lo estaba utilizando. Cuando pruebo el programa me salta un error en la linea 19 que es : pais, habitantes = linea.split(",")

Comment: pega el texto completo del mensaje de error

Comment: pais, habitantes = linea.split(",") # Dividimos cada linea en variables.

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: Como te dije, a chile le falta una coma, edita manualmente el archivo de registro para que tenga el formato correcto, lee mis notas.

Comment: Gracias, en caso de que tenga que agregar los nacimientos al lado de los habitantes, tendria que cambiar el codigo en la parte de pais, habitantes, nacimientos= linea.split(",") y en lineas[index] = "{0}, {1}".format(pais, int(habitantes), nacimientos)

Comment: O tendria que modificar otras cosas dentro del codigo?

Comment: Actualizo la respuesta con la respuesta a tu ultimo comentario.

Comment: Compruébalo tú mismo y si se te presenta algún problema exponlo y pide ayuda. No antes